# "Far enough removed" vs. "far removed enough" vs. "removed far enough"

Tags: grammaticality, adverbs, word-order, past-participles

Which of the following word orders is grammatical?

> 1. Games based on real life are sometimes not far enough removed.
> 2. Games based on real life are sometimes not far removed enough.
> 3. Games based on real life are sometimes not removed far enough.

Comment: All 3 are just fine grammatically.

Comment: ...but not idiomatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since "enough" qualifies "far", you should put it next to "far".  So number 2 is not so good, because it suggests that "enough" qualifies "removed", not "far".  But numbers 1 and 3 are both perfectly fine.

Comment: "far removed" is an idiom. http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/be-far-removed-from-sth

Answer (score -2):

> "Games based on real life are sometimes not far removed enough."

To convey the correct sense.
Other constructions do not seem to express the correct meaning.

[far removed](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/be-far-removed-from-sth) to be very different from something

Comment: Will the great scholar please stand up?

Comment: I don't really understand what your above comment means. Would you care to explain?

Comment: @Abluescarab I was addressing the learned down voter, expecting them to offer a comment. My comment meant: "I don't really understand your down vote. Would you care to explain?"